# second derivative of solutions to ODE with Lipschitz coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Just the simple ODE with Lipschitz coefficient $a$
\begin{align}
&\frac{d}{dx}h(x)=a(h(x))\\
&h(0)=x_0
\end{align}
We know that the existence and uniqueness holds and the solution is in $C^1$. Does the second derivative of the solution exist (in distributional sense perhaps)? How do I show it? So the solution is in $W^{2,p}$, what's $p$?

Answer (score 1):

Since $h$ is $C^1$, the composition $a(h(x))$ is Lipschitz. Hence $h' $ is Lipschitz. We can write this as $h\in C^{1,1}$. Or, if you prefer, $h\in W^{2, \infty }$ which says the same thing. All of this applies to finite time intervals, of course.